# Finding the azure account key with Blob Service Client fails(azure python sdk)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am using
Name: azure-mgmt-storage
Version: 16.0.0
Summary: Microsoft Azure Storage Management Client Library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python

for generating a report to find the storage container size.
The snippet of my code that I am using is as below

```py
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient

subscription_client = Subscription(tenant=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret)
service_principals = subscription_client.credentials
subscription_id = subscription_client.find_subscription_id()
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential=service_principals, subscription_id=subscription_id)
storage_account_list = storage_client.storage_accounts.list()
for storage_account in storage_account_list:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob,credential=service_principals)
                    account_info = blob_service_client.get_service_properties()
    keys = blob_service_client.credential.keys()
```

When I evaluate expression `blob_service_client.credential`, value is

```py
<azure.identity._credentials.client_secret.ClientSecretCredential object at 0x05747E98>
```

1. `blob_service_client.api_version` evaluates to `2020-02-10`.
2. And `blob_service_client.credential.account_key` or `blob_service_client.credential.account_key()` evaluates to `{AttributeError}'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'account_key'`
3. or even when I try `blob_service_client.credential.keys()` I get `{AttributeError}'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'keys'` error

Any Azure expert can help me out here? Also connnection strings are another way to approach this problem where I can use:

```py
BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
```

for which I am also required to generate the connection_string dynamically, which I am unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using the client secret credential, you can do your storage operation (calculating storage container size in this case). Note below in my code, I had the subscription id handy already, so I did not use subscription client. But you can definitely like your original code.

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient

tenant_id='<tenant id>'
client_id='<client id>'
client_secret='<secret>'
subscription_id='<subscription id>'

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential=credentials, subscription_id=subscription_id)
storage_account_list = storage_client.storage_accounts.list()
for storage_account in storage_account_list:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob,credential=credentials)
    containers = blob_service_client.list_containers()
    for container in containers:
        container_client = ContainerClient(account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob,credential=credentials, container_name=container.name)
        blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
        container_size = 0
        for blob in blobs:
            container_size = container_size + blob.size
        print('Storage Account: ' + storage_account.name + ' ; Container: ' + container.name + ' ; Size: ' + str(container_size))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got access to the keys with storage_client.storage_account.list_keys(resource_group_name, account_name). keys. The link is below:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/c509c6bf548ebe4918cd5f3503bcbd47ca982170/tools/azure-sdk-tools/devtools_testutils/storage_testcase.py#L68-L72

Comment: Also credentials object being too buggy I used the key as the required positional argument credential for creating container clients. If you can change the value of credential to key1 then I can accept your answer. Or you can provide an alternative way to provide credential as it may help other users.

Comment: "Also credentials object being too buggy" - can you be bit specific on the issue you observed?

Comment: Will post a separate question to it soon